# NSTableView: Updating data model based on user editing of a cell in an NSTableView

Tags: swift, nstableview

I have an NSTableView (two columns) that is populated with initial info. I want users to be able to directly edit cells by double clicking, entering text, then hitting return.

My NSTableView is cell based.

I don't understand how to capture the information the user enters in order to update my data model – that is to say, how do I get the string the user has entered into the cell they've edited?

I've tried several of the delegate methods and none seem to do what I'm looking for. I thought the most promising seemed to be:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, shouldEdit tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Bool
```

or,

```
func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification)
```

however I can't figure out how to get either to work as I'm not understanding how to access the string data in the cell.

Comment: Apple recommends using view-based table views.  Nonetheless you should be able to do with a cell based one.  Is the user editing the cell directly in the cell you create in your delegate's `tableView(_: dataCellFor:row:)` method?  Or do you pop-up some other view for them to edit?

Comment: Also in your `NSTableViewDataSource` subclass, have you implemented `tableView(_:setObjectValue:for:row:)`?  If the user is editing within the cell you provided, the tableview should call that method to set the updated data in your data source.

Comment: Currently I'm just emplementing:

func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any?

and

func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int

I'm expecting the user to just edit the cell(s) directly.

Comment: `tableView(_:objectValueFor:row:)` is what `NSTableView` calls to get the data from your data source to display.  That's half of what you need.  `textView(_:setObjectValue:for:row)` is the other half that sets the data back to your data source.

Comment: Thanks.
I implemented that method and cast the 'object' to a String and got what I needed.
(I'm not sure if I'm doing things correctly but it does seem to accomplish what I'm looking to do.)

   func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, setObjectValue object: Any?, for tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) {
        print("yes!")
        let newText : String = object as! String
        techs[row] = newText
    }

Comment: I'm glad it helped!